# Sscanf Problems with C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Hi I am having problems with `sscanf`. I am just trying to write a simple test program to help me understand how it works. The problem arises when writing to differents variables with `sscanf`. Here is what their values should be:

IP=175.85.10.147

number=2589

email = edward@gmail.com

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main() {
     char *toSend = "175.85.10.147:2589:edward@gmail.com";
     int *number;
     char IP[200];
     char email[300];
     sscanf(toSend, "%[^:]: %i%[^:]: ", IP, number, email);
     printf("%s", IP);
     printf("%i", number);
     printf("%s", email);
     return 0; 
 }
```

The IP it prints correct.

The number doesn't print correctly, which might be related to this warning I'm getting at compile time: `format '%i' expects argument of type 'int' but argument 2 has type 'int *'`.

The `email` variable just contains bizarre characters for some reason.

Comment: You passed a pointer to an int as an argument to a function that takes an int in that position. remove the `*` from the variable declaration so that it reads `int number;` and see if that works.

Comment: Well, let's deal with the warning first. `%i` expects an `int` and you're giving it `number` which is `int*`.

Comment: `int *number;` --> `int number;`,  `sscanf(toSend,"%199[^:]: %i:%299s", IP,  &number, email);`

Comment: `0100` means sixty-four, right?  if you disagree use `%d` instead if `%i`

Comment: @Jasen: you are **right**, `%i` will magically [parse `0` prefixed numbers as octal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: Dotted decimal notation should not have leading zeros, and neither should port numbers.  However, it is probably better safe than sorry — `%i` is probably not appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You need some memory to store number

i.e. change

```
int *number;
```

to

```
int number;
```

Then use

```
 sscanf(toSend,"%[^:]:%i:%[^:]",IP, &number, email);
```

I have also correct the typos - here is the code http://ideone.com/hpqGDZ

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main(){
  char *toSend = "175.85.10.147:2589:edward@gmail.com";
  int number;
  char IP[200];
  char email[300];
  if (sscanf(toSend, "%199[^:]:%i:%299[^:]", IP, &number, email) != 3) {
     return 1;
  }
  printf("%s\n", IP);
  printf("%i\n", number);
  printf("%s\n", email);
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I don't think passing a reference to `number` is correct, that'll still have the type `int*` won't it?

Comment: @ArnauVanBoschkenArnauB - Please use BLUEPIXY sscanf with the enhancement that avoid buffer overruns

Comment: Yes - Was thinking that myself. - Updated the answer. Not sure if assert is the best way to go - but it will do

Comment: assert should only be used for debug runs. It's designed to compile to nothing on release builds. So N = scanf(...)  assert(N ==3) is fine, but not to wrap the call.

Comment: Space before `%i` is redundant. There's absolutely no reason for it to be there.